# Unable to create maven project properly - facing error below

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

I have simply created maven project as

1. From the File menu, choose New, and then choose Project.
2. In the New Project window, choose Maven Project and click next
3. Select the archetype to “org.apache.axis2.archetype” quick start by entering “apache” in Filter box and click next.
4. Enter the Group Id and Artefact Id and click on Finish.

Adding Dependency into the `pom.xml` file:

&

Facing below error:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved.
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.1
```

Do I need to add other dependencies or use any other version for create maven project?

Comment: Please add your pom.xml to your question, otherwise this is hard to reproduce.